# Entity Framework, Transactions and Stored Procs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a stored procedure that writes data to a table, based on values from a different table. So, it reads the start/end dates from a table, then creates a whole lot of data and writes it to a separate table.

What happens is the user selects a Start/End date for something, and then I store the start/end date into a table. I then call the stored procedure, from within EF, and that procedures reads from the table just updated, and populates a different table.

If the proc fails, I want to roll back any data that the proc wrote, as well as the initial update of the table.

I think the data is only written to the table (The initial update, done in EF) when you call the 'SaveChanges'. So I call that, and THEN call the procedure. Is there a way to detect if the procedure failed, and if so, rollback ALL udpates (The table update, and anything the proc did)?

Currently, my code looks like this, but it seems a paremeter in SaveChanges is invalid (wants no parameters), and 'AcceptAllChanges' is invalid:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    Context.SaveChanges(false);
    Context.project_scheduled_event_payments(st.id);
    Context.AcceptAllChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a transaction scope. You'll need to add a reference to `System.Transactions.dll` and add a `using System.Transactions;`

From msdn:

> If you call SaveChanges() or SaveChanges(true),the EF simply assumes
>   that if its work completes okay, everything is okay, so it will
>   discard the changes it has been tracking, and wait for new changes.
>
> Unfortunately though if something goes wrong somewhere else in the
>   transaction, because the EF discarded the changes it was tracking, we
>   can’t recover.
>
> This is where SaveChanges(false) and AcceptAllChanges() come in.
>
> SaveChanges(false) tells the EF to execute the necessary database
>   commands, but hold on to the changes, so they can be replayed if
>   necessary.
>
> Now if the broader transaction fails you can retry the EF specific
>   bits, with another call to SaveChanges(false). Alternatively you can
>   walk through the state-manager to log what failed.
>
> Once the broader transaction succeeds, you simply call
>   AcceptAllChanges() manually, and the changes that were being tracked
>   are discarded.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) 
{ 
    //Do something with context1 

    //Save Changes but don't discard yet 
    context1.SaveChanges(false); 

    //run your secondary procedure, if it succeeds then:    
    //
    //
    context1.AcceptAllChanges(); 

}
```

**edit:** Okay, the above will not work since `.SaveChanges(false)` is an `ObjectContext` method (also deprecated for `.SaveChanges(SaveOptions)`) and we have a `DbContext`. We know `DbContext` is a wrapper around `ObjectContext`, so we can use an `IObjectContextAdapter` to get access to the `.SaveChanges(SaveOptions)` method:

First we'll need to add `using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;`, then:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) 
{ 
    // do something with your context


    // cast your context to IObjectContextAdapter to get access to the full SaveChanges(SaveOptions) method 

    IObjectContextAdapter contextAdapter = context;

    // .DetectChangesBeforeSave is the equivalent of .SaveChanges(false);
    contextAdapter.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(
        System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);

    //run your secondary procedure, if it succeeds then:    
    //
    //

    contextAdapter.ObjectContext.AcceptAllChanges();

    scope.Complete();

}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. Is this available in EF5? As I get the 'Can non identify symbol 'TransactionScope' issue.

Comment: @Craig Updated my answer, I believe you're just missing a reference.

Comment: Thanks @Tom - But now I am battling with SaveChanges. Doesn't want a boolean parameter. Wants zero arguments. Maybe I need to go to EF6, as I notice all docs seems to say "EF6 specific"?

Comment: Upgraded to EF6, but same issue. It seems it doesnt know what Context.AcceptAllChanges - nor does it want a parameter in SaveChanges. I'm wondering if I have my context setup incorrectly.

Comment: I'm generating my model from the DB... and I believe I am therefore, non-code-first? It's possible I've done something wrong though. When I setup my context, I do use: Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; - Could that cause an issue? I wouldn't think so..

Comment: @Craig no, the issue was the method I suggested is available on `ObjectContext` and we are working with a `DbContext`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Tom, I was going to do that before, but wasn't sure of the effects. The only concrete way to check success, is if the SaveChanges doesn't throw an exception. I that valid?